# Comparison between Newey-West (1987) and Hansen-Hodrick (1980)

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error, neweywest

**Question:** What are the main differences and similarities between using Newey-West (1987) and Hansen-Hodrick (1980) standard errors? In which situations should one of these be preferred over the other?

Notes:

- I do know how each of these adjustment procedures works; however, I have not yet found any document that would compare them, either online or in my textbook. **References are welcome!**
- Newey-West tends to be used as "catch-all" HAC standard errors, whereas Hansen-Hodrick comes up frequently in the context of overlapping data points (e.g. see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8373/time-series-regression-with-overlapping-data) or [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35216/how-can-you-determine-the-correct-significance-of-the-shiller-p-e-regression)). **Hence one important aspect of my question is, is there anything about Hansen-Hodrick that makes it *more* suited to deal with overlapping data than Newey-West?** (After all, overlapping data ultimately leads to serially correlated error terms, which Newey-West also deals with.)
- For the record, I am aware of [this similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308638/wondering-what-type-of-covariance-correction-for-standard-errors-is-better-hans), but it was relatively poorly posed, got downvoted and ultimately the question that I am asking here did not get answered (only the programming-related part got answered).

Comment: Aren't NW-type HAC estimators superseded by the fixed smoothing HAC estimators of [Kiefer & Vogelsang (2002)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3082033) & the subsequent literature?

Comment: In particular, you might want to read the opinion posts of Frank Diebold [here](https://fxdiebold.blogspot.in/2015/10/the-hac-emperor-has-no-clothes.html) & [here](https://fxdiebold.blogspot.in/2016/07/the-hac-emperor-has-no-clothes-part-2.html).

Comment: @tchakravarty That's an interesting thought, thanks for sharing! I'll have to back up a bit and first look into [Kiefer, Vogelsang and Bunzel (2000)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2999605). If you want to expand on your point in an answer, also explaining what this implies for Hansen-Hodrick-type estimators that deal with overlapping data, you'd have a very good chance of being awarded the bounty. (It would not be honest from me to guarantee it, obviously, since somebody else might write a competing answer, but so far my bounty has not proven very popular.)

Comment: @tchakravarty, the theoretical literature seems to settle on that, but in practice, these estimators are not yet in widespread use, I would say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider a class of long-run variance estimators

$$
\hat{J_T}\equiv\hat{\gamma}_0+2\sum_{j=1}^{T-1}k\left(\frac{j}{\ell_T}\right)\hat{\gamma}_j
$$
$k$ is a kernel or weighting function, the $\hat\gamma_j$ are sample autocovariances. $k$, among other things must be symmetric and have $k(0)=1$. $\ell_T$ is a bandwidth parameter.

[Newey & West (Econometrica 1987)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913610?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) propose the Bartlett kernel
$$k\left(\frac{j}{\ell_T}\right) = \begin{cases}
\bigl(1 - \frac{j}{\ell_T}\bigr)
\qquad &\mbox{for} \qquad 0 \leqslant j \leqslant \ell_T-1 \\
0 &\mbox{for} \qquad j > \ell_T-1
\end{cases}
$$

[Hansen & Hodrick's (Journal of Political Economy 1980)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1833137?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) estimator amounts to taking a truncated kernal, i.e., $k=1$ for $j\leq M$ for some $M$, and $k=0$ otherwise. This estimator is, as discussed by Newey & West, consistent, but not guaranteed to be positive semi-definite (when estimating matrices), while Newey & West's kernel estimator is.

Try $M=1$ for an MA(1)-process with a strongly negative coefficient $\theta$. The population quantity is known to be $J = \sigma^2(1 + \theta)^2>0$, but the Hansen-Hodrick estimator may not be:

```
set.seed(2)
y <- arima.sim(model = list(ma = -0.95), n = 10)
acf.MA1 <- acf(y, type = "covariance", plot = FALSE)$acf
acf.MA1[1] + 2 * acf.MA1[2]
## [1] -0.4056092
```

which is not a convincing estimate for a long-run *variance*.

This would be avoided with the Newey-West estimator:

```
acf.MA1[1] + acf.MA1[2]
## [1] 0.8634806
```

Using the `sandwich` package this can also be computed as:

```
library("sandwich")
m <- lm(y ~ 1)
kernHAC(m, kernel = "Bartlett", bw = 2,
  prewhite = FALSE, adjust = FALSE, sandwich = FALSE)
##             (Intercept)
## (Intercept)   0.8634806
```

And the Hansen-Hodrick estimate can be obtained as:

```
kernHAC(m, kernel = "Truncated", bw = 1,
  prewhite = FALSE, adjust = FALSE, sandwich = FALSE)    
##             (Intercept)
## (Intercept)  -0.4056092
```

See also `NeweyWest()` and `lrvar()` from `sandwich` for convenience interfaces to obtain Newey-West estimators of linear models and long-run variances of time series, respectively.

[Andrews (Econometrica 1991)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2938229?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) provides an analysis under more general conditions.

As to your subquestion regarding overlapping data, I would not be aware of a subject-matter reason. I suspect tradition is at the roots of this common practice.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but will probably only be able to review and hopefully accept over the weekend. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Just to clarify, your answer in effect says that Newey-West should be preferred over Hansen-Hodrick in all cases since the latter might "behave poorly", which "interferes with asymptotic confidence interval formation and hypothesis testing" (both quotes from Newey-West, 1987)?

Comment: PS. Could you please also clarify the source for "Andrews"?

Comment: I linked the papers to Jstor. As for the previous comments, indeed, when a variance estimate is not even guaranteed to be positive, we should also not expect it to be a good ingredient into confidence intervals and test statistics.