# Is the optimal lag length for the Hansen and Hodrick and Newey West robust standard errors the same?

Tags: least-squares, heteroscedasticity, lags, neweywest

Is the optimal lag length for the Hansen and Hodrick and Newey West robust standard errors the same?

I have read in Greene that the optimal is $T^{1/4}$ for Newey-West, is this the same for Hansen and Hodrick?

Answer (score 1):

No, the optimal lag length is not the same and it is not as simple as $\lfloor T^{1/4} \rfloor$. There are various data-driven lag/bandwidth selection techniques with Andrews (1991, *Econometrica*, **59**, 817-859) and Newey & West (1994, *Review of Economic Studies*, **61**, 631-653) being particularly prominent. (Plus the literature on bandwidth=sample size literature.)

See also this questions and corresponding answer for a more detailed
[Comparison between Newey-West (1987) and Hansen-Hodrick (1980)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312341/comparison-between-newey-west-1987-and-hansen-hodrick-1980).